# How to read a compressed csv-file with pandas read_csv in Watson Studio?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, zip, watson-studio

To read a zip-compressed csv-file with pandas in my local Jupyter notebook I execute:

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('csv_file.zip')
```

However, in Watson Studio, `read_csv()` throws an exception when I replace a filename with a cloud object storage streaming object.

This is the first cell of my notebook in Watson Studio:

```py
import types
from ibm_botocore.client import Config
import ibm_boto3

def __iter__(self): return 0

client = ibm_boto3.client(service_name='s3', ibm_api_key_id='...',
    ibm_auth_endpoint="...", config=Config(signature_version='oauth'),
    endpoint_url='...')

body = client.get_object(Bucket='...', Key='csv_file.zip')['Body']
if not hasattr(body, "__iter__"):
    body.__iter__ = types.MethodType( __iter__, body )
```

Now, when I try:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(body)
```

I get:

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbb in position 0: invalid start byte
```

If I specify `compression='zip'`:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(body, compression='zip')
```

the message is:

```
'StreamingBody' object has no attribute 'seek'
```

Is there a direct way to `read_csv()` a zipped file in Watson Studio without explicitly writing an unpacking code?

(The `pd.__version__` is `0.21.0` in both environments.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following procedure works if your file is already added as a data asset of your Watson Studio project.

1. Create a project token for your project. In your project, go to <kbd>Settings</kbd>, navigate to the <kbd>Access tokens</kbd> section and click in the option <kbd>New token</kbd> (it is enough to select "Viewer" in the "Access role for project" dropdown menu there).
2. Now, in your notebook in "edit" mode, there are three dots (<kbd>⋮</kbd>) on the top right corner of the screen and there you click insert your token. A new first cell will be added with your project credentials, now you run it.
3. Now you can use a code like this:

```py
file = project.get_file("my_compressed_csv.zip")
df = pd.read_csv(file, compression='zip')
```

The `read_csv()` option does not work directly in this situation in Watson Studio, so you need to use the [`project-lib`](https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/analyze-data/project-lib-python.html) library.